# applying multiple conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to fill an column with true or false, depending on whether a condition is met.
I know to use any() method, but I need to compare values of two columns. I tried and have not succeeded- using & gives type error.

my data looks something like

```
A   B   condition_met
1   2   
3   3
5   9
7   2
```

the expected output is something like
my data looks something like

```
A   B   condition_met
1   2   true
3   3   true
5   9   true
7   2   false
```

I want the value in condition_met if A>3 and B>4

What I tried was

```
df.loc[df['A'] > 3 & 'B' > 4, 'condition_met'] = 'True'
```

upd: I need to check if condition is met. i.e., if A>3 then B>4.
if A<=3 then it must still be true, since the condition doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you add expected ouput?

Comment: Do you need `df['condition_met'] = (df.A>3) & (df.B>4) | (df.A <= 3)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign mask with parantheses, because priority of operators:

```
df['condition_met'] = (df.A>3) & (df.B>4)
```

Or:

```
df['condition_met'] = df.A.gt(3) & df.B.gt(4)
```

Your solution - `'True'` if match else `NaN`s:

```
df.loc[(df['A'] > 3) & (df['B'] > 4), 'condition_met'] = 'True'
```

EDIT:

```
df['condition_met'] = (df.A>3) & (df.B>4) | (df.A <= 3)
print (df)
   A  B  condition_met
0  1  2           True
1  3  3           True
2  5  9           True
3  7  2          False
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
df['condition_met'] = (df.A > 3) & (df.B > 4)
```

Another possible approach is to use *logical_and* function from *Numpy*:

```
df['condition_met'] = np.logical_and(df.A.gt(3), df.B.gt(4))
```